# ¿Por qué me salen 3 números más?

Tags: c++, string, switch

Lo primero es que se que si pongo -3 ya está bién pero el problema es que no se donde está el error y ahora que todavía soy un novato me gustaría saber el error y por que pasa esto, lo único que he podido comprobar es que el error es a partir del for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    char frase[30];
    int vocalE = 0, vocalI = 0, vocalO = 0, vocalU = 0, numDeLetras, vocalA = 0;

    cout << "Escribe una frase: ";
    cin.getline(frase, 30, '\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        switch(frase[i]) {
            case 'e':
                vocalE++;
                break;
            case 'i':
                vocalI++;
                break;
            case 'o':
                vocalO++;
                break;
            case 'u':
                vocalU++;
                break;
            case 'a':
                vocalA++;
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nVocal a: " << vocalA << "\n" << "Vocal e: " << vocalE << "\n" << "Vocal i: " << vocalI << "\n" << "Vocal o: " << vocalO << "\n" << "Vocal u: " << vocalU << endl;

    system("pause>main.o");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para aclarar cual es el resultado esperado y cual es el que estás obteniendo?

Answer (score 1):

Tu `for` siempre recorre el String `frase` en su totalidad es decir siempre lo haces de 0 a 29. ¿Que pasa si escribo `Hola`?  En `frase` solo ocupa los 4 primeros posiciones. Para este caso solo deberías evaluar las 4 primeras cierto y no las 30 porque no sabes lo que habrá en los restantes..

Tu `for` debería ser:

```
   for(i=0; i<strlen(frase);i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días también podrías probar con añadiendole un = al for de la de la respuesta de Juan Carlos Guibovich
for(i=0; i<=strlen(frase);i++)